# PHP Arrays difference between [0] and ['0']

Tags: php, arrays

Hello all I'm working on a program and sometimes with php I call an array like for example this:

```
$sales['data'][0]['id'];
```

but if I do `$sales['data']['0']['id'];`

It returns the same value. Does it matter in some cases if i add the quoting marks or is it all the same? I'm asking this because I want to make sure I'm using the best method possible for this.

Comment: no difference in case of numeric indexed array